# Tag Mismatch using RememberMe token with Shiro

Tags: java, spring-boot, shiro, remember-me

A few releases ago of my website, I started getting the following warnings showing up in my error logs over and over again.

```
Message:
Delegate RememberMeManager instance of type [org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.CookieRememberMeManager] threw an exception during getRememberedPrincipals().

Exception:
org.apache.shiro.crypto.CryptoException: Unable to execute 'doFinal' with cipher instance [Cipher.AES/GCM/NoPadding, mode: decryption, algorithm from: SunJCE].
    at org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.crypt(JcaCipherService.java:462)
    at org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.crypt(JcaCipherService.java:445)
    at org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.decrypt(JcaCipherService.java:390)
    at org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.decrypt(JcaCipherService.java:382)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AbstractRememberMeManager.decrypt(AbstractRememberMeManager.java:482)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AbstractRememberMeManager.convertBytesToPrincipals(AbstractRememberMeManager.java:419)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AbstractRememberMeManager.getRememberedPrincipals(AbstractRememberMeManager.java:386)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.getRememberedIdentity(DefaultSecurityManager.java:613)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.resolvePrincipals(DefaultSecurityManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.createSubject(DefaultSecurityManager.java:347)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject$Builder.buildSubject(Subject.java:845)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.subject.WebSubject$Builder.buildWebSubject(WebSubject.java:148)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.createSubject(AbstractShiroFilter.java:292)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:141)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.helpers.MDCInsertingServletFilter.doFilter(MDCInsertingServletFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:623)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1118)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1055)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:855)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2207)
    at org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.crypt(JcaCipherService.java:459)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

I made no changes in regards to my RememberMe token (that I know of) such as my cypher key during this time. I do try to keep my supporting libraries up-to-date so it is possible that one of the upgrades caused this but I otherwise have no real idea. The strange thing is that my website seems unaffected, no one has reported problems with the RememberMe token not remembering them. I would love to know what is going on so I can get rid of these warnings to feel secure again about my site. Any help greatly appreciated. Here are some relevant 3rd-party packages I'm currently using...

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
          <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

UPDATE:

I should say that my Remember Cookie is configured via the following code:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringBeanConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager securityManager() {
        DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        securityManager.setRealm(<myRealm>;

        CookieRememberMeManager rmm = new CookieRememberMeManager();
        rmm.setCipherKey(Base64.decode(<cipher key string>));
        securityManager.setRememberMeManager(rmm);

        return securityManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make some guesses assumptions.

- That message was logged, but the request did not fail?
- you recently updated from Shiro < 1.4.2 ?

If so it sounds like this could be related to CVE-2019-12422
The default remember-me encryption format had changed because of this.
While we recommend you do not revert back to the previous format, there are instructions on how to do that in this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-730

Comment: Yes, that is **exactly** what I am seeing. As mentioned the exception gets logged as a warning and since no one has complained about the site I assume all the requests are going forward. So, sure I could revert but since it is not recommended, what can I do to make it work the way it is now intended? There is no instructions for that. I am not using any config file so using the defaults.

Comment: I've updated showing how I'm configuring my CookieRememberMeManager.

Comment: The warning happens when a user presents an "old" remember me cookie when they access your site. Shiro will delete the cookie (instruct the browser to delete it), if the user is not logged in, or issue a new once if they are (or the next time the log in).

Comment: Once all your users log in again you would no longer see these warnings.  If you have thousands of users, and you consider this log spam, you could override the relevant method, and manage it differently: https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/mgt/AbstractRememberMeManager.java

Comment: Aaah, so its just a waiting game then.  :) It does seem to have slowed. So my user base is just slowly getting up-to-date and eventually these messages will disappear if I understand you correctly. Thank you!!